Error on drivers
devadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0b:00.0 ==
i have this error trying to update nvidia drivers

Given you've provided little details (what Ubuntu product & release you're using, the actual command you used) and only a partial paste from unknown command, our ability to help is currently minimal.  Providing some context would allow us to help you.

Ubuntu 24.04.01,in the "software and updates">other drivers says that It is unknow.It has got the lastest NVIDIA drivers
